# Null pointer exception for alerts: JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, serenity-bdd

Here is my code:

```
public class BasePage extends PageObject {

  @Managed
   WebDriver driver;

    
    public Alert waitingForAlert() throws InterruptedException {
        Alert al = driver.switchTo().alert();
        return al;
    }
```

I'm getting the error

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.switchTo()" because "this.driver" is null

Comment: Have you set the property for the web driver anywhere? If I have to guess, I think the problem (as the error indicates) the web driver is null. If you don't tell the test runner where to obtain the `.exe` file to properly instantiate the driver, this is the most likely result.

Comment: It took me a while to figure what this `@Managed` annotation was because I never used it. Is this part of `net.thucydides`? If so, this is not correct at all as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error only because of using driver before creating an instance of it.
Let's suppose you want to run this test case on Chrome and your PageObject class doesn't have Chrome Driver instance (if yes it will create new chrome driver instance again which is not supposed to do)

```
  WebDriver driver; 


public Alert waitingForAlert() throws InterruptedException {
    Alert al = driver.switchTo().alert(); 
    return al;
}
```

The nullPointer exception comes from this line: `driver.switchTo().alert();`
in order to use driver you should create an instance of it. Meaning you can do it by typing:

```
class BasePage extends PageObject {



 @Managed
   WebDriver driver;

public void setDriver()
{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","<Path of ChromeDriver.exe here>"); 
     driver = new ChromeDriver(); // Creating new 'ChromeDriver' instance
}

    public Alert waitingForAlert() throws InterruptedException {
    setDriver();
    Alert al = driver.switchTo().alert(); 
    return al;
}
```

`}`

Comment: this opens blank pages during my test which doesn't close. The null pointer exception is gone though

Comment: I explained to you how to handle null pointer exception which is mentioned in your question. You should refactor your code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is that driver is still null because BasePage has not yet been instantiated. You will have to override the navigateTo method in some way to create a driver.

```
class BasePage extends PageObject {

  @Managed
   WebDriver driver;

    
    public Alert waitingForAlert() throws InterruptedException {
        Alert al = driver.switchTo().alert();
        return al;
    }

    public void navigateTo() { // your code here ... }
}
```

Comment: Is this a guess or an answer?

Comment: This is an answer

Comment: I don't think this is the case.

Comment: How does `public void navigateTo() { // your code here ... }` addresses _`this.driver`_ error?

Comment: The `navigateTo` method will be called once on the page object. This will give a
working WebDriver instance to your `PageObject` constructor, which is what you
are trying to get at.